# SSDT Visual Studio 2013 - Same solution - reference a database project in SSIS project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

- SSIS 2014
- SQL Server 2014
- SSDT Visual Studio 2013

I have one solution with two projects under it IS.dtproj and DB.sqlproj. One for SSIS development and one for the related database development.

Is it possible to reference the DB.sqlproj in the IS.dtproj project's connection manager? Currently I can create connection manager on sql server database as usual. However I cannot create connection manager on Projects that are listed in SQL Server Object Explorer.

The idea is, I first want try new developments e.g. I want to create new table but I don’t want to create this on the server yet - so I create them in DB.sqlproj - I want to use this new table in a SSIS package in IS.dtproj. Once I'm happy, I will build and publish both ispac and dacpac together onto the server. Is there a way currently to do this in SSDT Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not having a local instance of SQL Server to develop against? Therefore you can test without having it interfere with what is on the server.

Comment: It is a development server. However it is a shared development server, a change affects others as well. The db is too big to have individual local instance for each developer.

Comment: Are you saying that you think the same database will take up less space if it's in Visual Studio than it would in a local database instance?

Comment: It will take no size. You need a valid schema for SSIS to be able to get and set the metadata from. It cannot use a database project file as you're intending. With the 4.0 release of Mist and the capability for offline schema stuff, yeah, you could do it like that but now you're going to need to learn biml *and* buy a Mist license ~4k